# Moment generating functions and normal random variables.

Tags: probability

Suppose that the distribution of students' grades in a probability
test is normal, with mean 72 and variance 25.
i.) What is the probability that the average grade of a class with
25 students is 75 or more?

I ended up with $X~N(1800,225)$, $E[X]=25(72)=1800$ and standard deviation $=225$ and my answer was $1-P(.3\le Z)$

ii.)If a professor teaches two different sections of this course,
each containing 25 students, what is the probability that the
average of one class is at least three more than the average
of the other class?

Comment: Why "moment generating functions" in the title?

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

i) the distribution of the mean of $n$ iid normal random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

You might also note that the standard deviation of the sum should have been $125$, and that $\dfrac{1875-1800}{125}=0.6$.

ii) the distribution of the difference of $2$ iid normal random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $2\sigma^2$.